# Manipulating SurveyMonkey Results & data

Tags: surveymonkey

we wud like to webscrape / import surveymonkey results into a html page then approve/decline each survey from/on that page.

We can also use wordpress as a last resort if we must.

Any ideas/tip how we can do this programatically ?  Api Tips ???

Tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SurveyMonkey API](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3) to fetch the responses and render them how you like.

You can fetch the [survey details](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-details) like this:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/details
```

You can fetch the [survey responses](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#survey-responses) like this:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses
```

You can then join the two data together to fill it out. This may be quite a bit of work to render all that yourself though, you may just want to have a list of edit/analyze URLs (provided in the body when fetching responses) and then click through to SurveyMonkey to view the response and decide.

Fetch them [in bulk](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-responses-bulk) like this:

```
GET /v3/surveys/<survey_id>/responses/bulk
```

and make a table with a list of URLs to work with. You may think of other ideas by looking at the API docs.